# The 90 day rule in the Schengen area: When can I go again?

Tags: schengen, spain

I am from the UK and have been visiting Spain throughout the last year for 2-3 weeks at a time. I am trying to work out when I can visit Spain/the Schengen area again as I have stayed there for a total of 89 days now.

From the day I entered Spain to the last time I came home it has been over 180 days. Does this mean my 90 days have reset and I can go again without waiting?

I've read mixed articles saying you have to wait another 90 days to go again but I've basically spent 89 days in Spain in the last 180 days and the rest of that time I've been in the UK.

Comment: You can put your travel history into https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/content/visa-calculator_en along with a planned date of entry to see whether you can enter on that date and, if so, how many days you will be able to stay.  You can ignore any visit that ended more than 180 days ago.  Your 90 days are completely reset after being away from the Schengen area for 90 or more days; you have been out for over 180 days so you are well past that point.  If you go for three weeks every two months, you can maintain that pattern indefinitely without interruption.

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment is incorrect because I misread something in the question.  I thought you said "from the last time I came home it has been over 180 days."  So I suppose you _haven't_ been out for more than 180 days.  If you want to know whether you could stay if you returned tomorrow, then you should count up the number of days you spent in Spain since November 6 and see whether that number is less than 90.  If you want to know how long you could stay if you returned on Thursday, count from November 7th.  Etcetera.

Comment: @phoog thank you very much for clarifying this, this definitely clears things up :)

Comment: Another correction: if you count the days of presence from November 6th, it has to be less than 89, because you need an available day to use.  That is, if the number is 89 and you enter on May 4th, that's your 90th day in the 180-day period from November 6th through May 4th.

Comment: One of the benefits of the *Entry/Exit System (EES)* that (may, possibly, ..., who knows) be introduced later this year is that you can login to your account at any time and it will tell you how many days you have left.

Comment: Argh, another correction: the number must be less than _or equal to_ 89, which means that it must be less than 90; the initial statement was correct.  This stuff is confusing!  The calculator is really the way to go, or, eventually, the EES as mentioned by @MarkJohnson